# Why isn't my check for a sub string working?

Tags: java

Im trying to a really simply condition statement. I need to check if my string first character is equal to 0.

I have a string that is equal to 0123, and I want to see if the first character is equal to 0.

```
String timetest = "0123";

if (timetest.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
    System.out.println("first character is equal to 0");
} else {
    System.out.println(time.toString().substring(0,2));
}
```

I dont get why it isn't printing "first character is equal to 0"?

Sorry for the simple question. I don't see why this isn't working.

Comment: use .`equals` and not `==`. read about it to understand what is the difference

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Oh of course. Thank you !

Comment: Hint: everything you can dream of asking as newbie ... has been asked before. Try using a search engine before posting your next question ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Preach Brother!

Comment: @JackFlamp I leave the preaching to people with more criminal energy. Me, I just hit the close-as-duplicate button quickly ;-)